# Norm of Matrix transpose

Tags: matrices, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

I have a problem below:

Let $\|\cdot\|$ denotes the norm matrix
\begin{equation}
\|A\|=\max \frac {\|Ax\|}{\|x\|},
\end{equation}
for every $A$.

Now suppose that $H: \mathbb{R}^k \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^k \times \mathbb{R}^d$ is a matrix-valued function such that $\|H\|=O(\|x\|).$ What can we say about $\|H^T\|$? Thanks for any help.

Comment: The norm of every matrix is bounded.

Comment: Thanks @copper.hat, I think I misunderstood. But, I've corrected now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All norms on $\mathbb{R}^n$ are equivalent (and on $\mathbb{R}^m \times \mathbb{R}^n$ as well, of course).

So you can use the Frobenius norm, and since $\|H\|_F = \|H^T \|_F$, whatever you can say about $H$, you can say about $H^T$ (with appropriate constant factors, of course).